# Hardening TLS web server Apache settings

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, hardening

*OS: GNU/Linux Debian 9.2, fully updated.*

Under the title *Hardening TLS web server Apache settings* I mean the following:

- disabling TLS 1.0, already done with this setting:

  ```
  SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
  ```

  in the following file:

  ```
  /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf
  ```
- disabling GZIP compression, already done with the following command:

  ```
  a2dismod deflate
  ```

  although it asked me if I really want to disable this module, I had to type:

  > Yes, do as I say!

  so naturally, I had some serious doubts, but it seems not to cause any issues.

  I originally thought, that setting:

  ```
  SSLCompression Off
  ```

  would do the trick, but it seems to serve another purpose, anyway going forward...
- Setting a few useful Headers:

  ```
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"

  Header always set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"

  Header always set X-XSS-Protection: 1

  Header always set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'none'; script-src 'none'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self'"

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  ```
- Switching to 256-bit encryption:

  ```
  SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM256:DH+AESGCM256:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:RSA+AESGCM256:RSA+AES256:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!eNULL:!ADH:!EXP:!LOW:!PSK:!SRP:!RC4
  ```

  This is my main question, as I did not know how to do the switch properly, so I simply added `256` everywhere. Surprisingly, it works:) But is the line correct?

I hope I didn't mess up too much.

---

Tested on SSLLabs and many other sites, but if you want quick info, you might want to use:

https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/

The website I am securing is:

https://www.zalohovaniburian.cz/

(It does not yet contain anything more than "Under Construction" image.)

---

**EDIT1:**

- I generated a larger DHParameters file with:

  ```
  openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 4096
  ```

  and insured it is R/W-able only by `root`.
- Finally, I included it in the file:

  ```
  /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
  ```

  with the line:

  ```
  SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/dhparams.pem"
  ```

---

**EDIT2:**

I bought a *normal* SSL certificate, so late today I replaced the free Let's Encrypt, there has been before for a SpaceSSL.

---

**EDIT3:**

In addition to the above, I can't find out:

- What DNS CAA is my certificate using?
- How to enable OCSP Must-Staple?

Comment: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS is a good starting point

Comment: `deflate` and SSLCompression have nothing to do with each other. You can use `deflate` completely independently from SSL, it will work the same way for pure HTTP domains. `deflate` enables compression at the HTTP level, which sits over the TLS/SSL level, in which you can have compression too, or not, depending on the `SSLCompression` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your domain does not have a CAA record. If you do `dig CAA zalohovaniburian.cz` you will not get a reply. Compare with `dig CAA google.com`. If you want to use it you will need to provision it in your zone, like `www.zalohovaniburian.cz. CAA 128 issue "spacessl.com"` but double check with the CA you are using (SpaceSSL)
2. As for OCSP you have some information in the guide given by Håkan Lindqvist at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#OCSP_Stapling ; this article gives detailed howto on how to add OCSP Stapling to Apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ocsp-stapling-on-apache-and-nginx

PS: have a look at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ for online SSL checking, it has a good interface with links on how to remedy to various problems detected.
Your website gets an A+, this is very good!